# Issue with access of Firestore Data of Date

Tags: swift, firebase, date, swiftui

I am having issues accessing my startDate: Date data once I have it from the Firestore database.
Data stored in FireStore:

```
struct dateSetting: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var startDate: Date
}
```

How I am fetching data:

```
func fetchPosts() async throws -> [dateSetting] {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return [] }
    let snapshot = try await startDateReference1.document(uid).collection("startDate")
        .order(by: "startDate", descending: true)
        .getDocuments()
    return snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
        try! document.data(as: dateSetting.self)
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
@Published var startDateData: Loadable<[dateSetting]> = .loading

...

func fetchDatePosts() {
    Task {
        do {
            startDateData = .loaded( try await startDateRepository.fetchPosts())
            print(startDate)
        } catch {
            print("[TravelStartDateViewModel] Cannot fetch posts: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

> loaded([Days_Checker.dateSetting(id: 99F73F53-C527-4D8E-8D2A-F3D227CE1F5E, startDate: 2023-05-04 13:30:00 +0000)])

I can access the data as a list in the view:
View:

```
List(viewModel.startDateData) { date in
    DateRowsView(startDate: date)
    ...
```

RowView:

```
struct DateRowsView: View {
    
    let startDate: dateSetting

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {      
            Text(dateFormatter.string(from: startDate.startDate))
            ...
```

However I can not get access to the startDateData to withdraw the startDate and put it into a new variable so I can do calculations on it.

I have used this code to get access to a separate Type variable:

```
func fetchTheTypePosts() {
    Task {
        do {
            let fetchedType = try await typeRepository.fetchPosts()
            theType = calculateType(ty: fetchedType)
            print("theType: " + theType)
        } catch {
            print("[TravelTypeViewModel] Cannot fetch posts: \(error)")
            type = .error(error)
        }
    }
}

func calculateType(ty: [typeSetting]) -> String {
    let totalType = ty.reduce("") { $0 + $1.type }
    return totalType
}
```

But I am struggling with a way to extract the Date from:
loaded([Days_Checker.dateSetting(id: 99F73F53-C527-4D8E-8D2A-F3D227CE1F5E, startDate: 2023-05-04 13:30:00 +0000)])
Any transformations I attempt to add it to
var theStartDate: Date
give...

> Error: Cannot convert return expression of type '[dateSetting]' to return type 'Date'

Please help or ask for me to clarify anything.
Thanks

Using reduce and filter on the dateSetting unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fetchPosts` method returns an *array* of `dateSetting` objects. To get the `startDate` from one of them you'll have to pick one of the elements. e.g.

```
if let date = try await fetchPosts()?.first
{
   print(date.startDate)
}
```